# DatePicker day, month & year attributes for two-way data binding missing?

Tags: android, datepicker, android-databinding

I want to get the selected date of a `DatePicker` via two-way data binding.
Following [this guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way#two-way-attributes) from Google, there should be three attributes for my `DatePicker`,

```
android:year
android:month
android:day
```

which are intended for the two-way data binding.

However, those attributes do not appear for my `DatePicker`.

Am I missing out on some dependency, maybe? How can I get the selected date, using two-way data binding?

**This is the `DatePicker`s XML:**

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/date_picker"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline_end"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline_start"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline_top"
    />
```

Comment: Can you clarify on what step are you now - 1. You tried to put these attributes, but in XML layout there was some message (error) that no such attributes and you stopped. 2. You put these attributes to XML, connected them to some int values (maybe, VieModel?) and: 3. Then you tried to build and got some error. 4. You tried to build - no error - but your didn't get in UI what you want.

Comment: @sergiytikhonov Hi, I have tried to put the attributes. It is building and running. The observer's callback is not triggered on change. And Lint says "Unknown attribute".

Comment: Can you then show: 1. Your DatePicker in XML in a state when you tried to put the attributes, 2. ViewModel's fields that you bind to this attributes 3. Observer's callback that you expect to be triggering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've done to check your problem (still I see message about unknown attribute as well, but except that there no problem):

In XML:

```
<DatePicker
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:datePickerMode="spinner"
     android:year="@={viewModel.year}"
     android:month="@={viewModel.month}"
     android:day="@={viewModel.day}"
     android:onDateChanged="@{(v, year, month, day) -> viewModel.onDateChanged(year, month, day)}"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In ViewModel:

```
var year: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData(2020)
var month: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData(5)
var day: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData(22)

fun onDateChanged(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int){
    Log.v("Test_Picker", "$year $month $day")
}
```

So after date's change ViewModel's onDateChanged invokes and I can observe changes of LiveData's year/month/day in Fragment

Answer (score 0):

you can get the data from the listener:

```
 date_picker.setOnDateChangedListener { datePicker, year, month, day ->

       Log.v("Rene", "Year: $year Month: $month Day: $day")

 }
```

Or directly calling the DatePicker

```
  date_picker.dayOfMonth
  date_picker.month
  date_picker.year
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I know that I can get the information on another way, just like you explained here. Since I am using data binding, I also want to get the information using the two-way data binding, just like it is explained in the article from Google, above.

Comment: @RenéSpies did you follow this steps? enable data binding in build.gradle?https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-databinding/#0

Comment: Yes, of course. I am using data binding in this project on multiple occurrences.